# Format to represent a tree or node graph

Tags: java, formatting

I had build a tree to represent multiple connections between pages and links.
And now i want to print the tree to a document.I can do it to a txt file with some sort of format but **Is there any good formats to represent trees or node graphs ?** 
And any good Java framework or library to do it?

Comment: Do you want to save it for human viewing, or for reading back into the program later?

Comment: do you heard about project called "hands free wiki"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and more specifically the [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf) command.  This command takes a text file and renders it as a graph.  So, you could write out your data as a text file in the dot format and then could later use that with the dot command to visualize it if you wanted.

A simple example of the dot format given in the PDF link above is below.

```
digraph G {
  main -> parse -> execute;
  main -> init;
  main -> cleanup;
  execute -> make_string;
  execute -> printf
  init -> make_string;
  main -> printf;
  execute -> compare;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a depth first algorithm to print the contents to a text file.  For each level of the tree, use a toString method to generate the text for that node.  Then for each sublevel, do the same, but append a "+" or maybe a number to the front of the line so you know how deep in the tree it is.